# LINQ compare 2 lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm actually having some problems about a query. I'll try to make it simple to understand

I have a class that contains two attributes likes this

```
public class LanguageAndKnowledge{
public String LanguageCode{get;set;}
public int LanguageKnowledge{get;set;}
}
```

I use an other class which is from the EntityFramework mapped according to  the database

```
public class Student{
...
  public virtual ICollection<StudentLanguage> StudentLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

and the StudentLanguage class ..

```
 public partial class StudentLanguage
    {
        public int StudentLanguageID { get; set; }
        public System.Guid StudentID { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public int KnowledgeLevelID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> C_CreationDate { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
        public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    }
```

Now , it starts to be tricky. I have a list LanguageAndKnowledge so it looks like this

```
List<LanguageAndKnowledge> listLanguageKnowledge;
```

So I started to filter my data on my Student object with a query like this and it works

```
   IQueryable<Student> students = model.Student.Where(stud => stud.StudentStudy.Any(study => selectedStudyType.Contains(study.StudyTypeID.Value)
                                                                                                    && selectedStudyDegree.Contains(study.StudyDegreeID.Value)
                                                                                                    && selectedYears.Contains(study.CompletionDate.Value.Year)));
```

**The second step is to select from Student.StudentLanguage all the student that have the corresponding data from my List** . The language code and the knowledge id are the some in both classes. But I dont get how I should build the query.    I tried different things, like using the Any(),Contains() but I didnt get what I wanted.
I dont really get how I should compare the two lists and I need help :(

For example, I tried things like this..

```
students.Where(stud=> stud.StudentLanguage
.Any(lang=>listLanguageKnowledge.Contains(lang.LanguageCode)&&listLanguageKnowledge.Contains(lang.KnowledgeLevelId);
//or
students.Where(stud=> stud.StudentLanguage
.Any(lang=>listLanguageKnowledge.Any(lang.LanguageCode)&&listLanguageKnowledge.Any(lang.KnowledgeLevelId);
```

---

**Edit**
Data

> StudentLanguage
> Stud1 EN  4
> Stud1 NL  4
> Stud1 FR  4
> Stud2 FR  3
> Stud2 NL  4
> Stud3 EN  4
> Stud3 NL  4
> Stud3 FR  2
>
> `List<LanguageAndKnowledge>`
> EN    4
> NL    4
> FR    4
>
> Expected Result : Stud1

So I have to get all the data that match the list. I need to get all the student who has the code and the correct knowledge id

Comment: Please provide your sample data and an expected result.

Comment: In your attempts I'm pretty sure you're still doing a single comparison (students where this 1 property has this 1 exact value) but really you need to do that multiple times and aggregate the results (students where a or b or c ...) . There are many routes you could take but the simplest would just be to iterate one collection with a for loop, call where on the other collection inside of it and append the results to a collection you allocate prior to the loop. After the loop you probably gotta dedupe the list. Hope that helps you in the right direction.

Comment: Did you assign the result of students.Where(..) back to the students variable? In your example at the end of your question, the result of the .Where is discarded. E.g. change it to students = students.Where(....);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I understood that you need to find Students who knows all the language codes with required KnowledgeLevelId. I managed to Replicate to found the fix (unless I understood the problem wrong).

**My Result does match your expected result.**

## I created these classes:

```
public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<StudentLanguage> StudentLanguages { get; set; }
    }

    public class StudentLanguage
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public int KnowledgeLevelId { get; set; }
    }

    public class LanguageKnowledge
    {
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public int KnowledgeLevelId { get; set; }
    }
```

## Then I wrote this code to populate your mentioned data:

```
private static List<Student> PopulateData()
        {
            var students = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student()
                {
                    Name = "Student1",
                    StudentLanguages = new List<StudentLanguage>()
                    {
                        new StudentLanguage {KnowledgeLevelId = 4, LanguageCode = "EN"},
                        new StudentLanguage {KnowledgeLevelId = 4, LanguageCode = "NL"},
                        new StudentLanguage {KnowledgeLevelId = 4, LanguageCode = "FR"},
                    }
                }
                ,
                new Student()
                {
                    Name = "Student2",
                    StudentLanguages = new List<StudentLanguage>()
                    {
                        new StudentLanguage {KnowledgeLevelId = 3, LanguageCode = "FR"},
                        new StudentLanguage {KnowledgeLevelId = 4, LanguageCode = "NL"},
                    }
                },
                new Student()
                {
                    Name = "Student3",
                    StudentLanguages = new List<StudentLanguage>()
                    {
                        new StudentLanguage {KnowledgeLevelId = 4, LanguageCode = "EN"},
                        new StudentLanguage {KnowledgeLevelId = 4, LanguageCode = "NL"},
                        new StudentLanguage {KnowledgeLevelId = 2, LanguageCode = "FR"}
                    },
                }
            };
            return students;
        }
```

## And then this method to Find The Required data:

```
private void FindData()
        {
            var students = PopulateData();

            var languageKnowledges = new List<LanguageKnowledge>
            {
                new LanguageKnowledge { KnowledgeLevelId = 4, LanguageCode = "EN"},
                new LanguageKnowledge { KnowledgeLevelId = 4, LanguageCode = "NL"},
                new LanguageKnowledge { KnowledgeLevelId = 4, LanguageCode = "FR"},
            };

            var studentLanguage = students.Where(
                    student => DoesStudentHaveAllSkills(languageKnowledges, student.StudentLanguages));

            foreach (var student in studentLanguage)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(student.Name);
            }
        }



        public bool DoesStudentHaveAllSkills(List<LanguageKnowledge> languageKnowledges, List<StudentLanguage> studentLanguages)
        {
            return
                languageKnowledges.All(langKnow => studentLanguages.Any(studLang => studLang.KnowledgeLevelId.Equals(langKnow.KnowledgeLevelId)
                                                           && studLang.LanguageCode.Equals(langKnow.LanguageCode)));
        }
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking. If I understand correctly your code , i should get the first and this is exactly what I need .
I'm currently working on my code because I discovered some other bugs .. lol 
A big thanks you :)

Comment: No Problem @Seb, don't forget to accept the answer ;-). New to the community so trying to build some repo lolz

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by

> all the student that have the corresponding data from my List

but this might work for you:

```
students.Where(stud => stud.StudentLanguage.Any(
    lang => listLanguageKnowledge.Any(lk => lk.LanguageCode == lang.LanguageCode && 
                                            lk.KnowledgeLevelId == lang.KnowledgeLevelId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it doesn't work, please provide a sample of both lists.

```
students.Where(stud=> stud.StudentLanguage
    .Any(lang=>listLanguageKnowledge
         .Any(listItem => (listItem.LanguageCode == lang.LanguageCode) &&
                          (listItem.LanguageKnowledge == lang.KnowledgeLevelId)
             )
        ));
```